# twilio inbound message over 160 characters reassable as one message

Tags: twilio

I have tried different ways for inbound sms reassebling but failed therefore how to enable twilio configuration for sms reassembling if message is greater than 160 characters

Comment: Just to add to what Marcos said, Twilio should be automatically re-assembling inbound messages > 160 chars for you.  If you're not seeing that its possible the carrier you are sending from is not attributing the messages in a way that lets us do that.  I'd suggest opening a ticket with our support crew to see if they can dig deeper into the issue.  If you do, make sure you include some example message Sids.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio will concatenate the messages automatically for you. In fact it is possible to concatenate messages up to 1600 characters as you can see [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181508-Does-Twilio-support-concatenated-SMS-messages-or-messages-over-160-characters-).

However, some carriers will not support that, which means that even when Twilio concatenates the messages, they will be split up when showing on the device. Some devices will also have limitations to that, so concatenation really is limited to your carrier and device. We support concatenated message both ways. you can read more about it [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181508-Does-Twilio-support-concatenated-SMS-messages-or-messages-over-160-characters-) for outbound messages.

Hope this helps you